# Cannot loop through XML nodes in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a file where I store comments. The file name is **comments.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<comment>
  <user>User4251</user>
  <date>02.10.2018</date>
  <text>Comment body goes here</text>
</comment>
<comment>
  <user>User8650</user>
  <date>01.10.2018</date>
  <text>Comment body goes here</text>
</comment>
```

To loop through the XML tree, I am using the example given at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp) (with some modifications to the parameters). The code is contained in **index.php**:

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("comments.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
  foreach($xml -> children() as $comments) { 
    echo $comments -> user . ", "; 
    echo $comments -> date . ", "; 
    echo $comments -> text . "<br>";
  }
?>
```

As per the example, I am expecting:

```
User4251, 02.10.2018, Comment body goes here
User8650, 02.10.2018, Comment body goes here
```

However, I am getting three errors:

> **Warning:** simplexml_load_file(): comments.xml:7: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in **192.168.0.1/users/User8650/index.php** on line **2**
>
> **Warning:** simplexml_load_file():  in **192.168.0.1/users/User8650/index.php** on line **2**
>
> **Warning:** simplexml_load_file(): ^ in **192.168.0.1/users/User8650/index.php** on line **2**
>
> **Error:** Cannot create object

The fourth one is due to the `die()` statement.

Is the example erroneous or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Your missing a container, e.g. https://3v4l.org/StGhH.

Comment: Using `$xml -> children()` in your loop can mean that it will pick up any child node type, it is usually better to read it with `$xml->comment` to specify the comment nodes (assuming you have a root node as others have mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Currently I only have `<comment>` elements, but I am planning to add more later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a valid [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) in your XML document. This will work:

```
<root_example>
 <comment>
   <user>User4251</user>
   <date>02.10.2018</date>
   <text>Comment body goes here</text>
  </comment>
  <comment>
   <user>User8650</user>
   <date>01.10.2018</date>
   <text>Comment body goes here</text>
 </comment>
</root_example>
```

Comment: Never thought it is as simple as that :)

Comment: It never is haha. I guess "comments" would be a decent name for a container here.

Comment: Yes, I added it as `<comments>`.