# XML child element does not get added but does not throw any errors

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

*Following up from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597287/cannot-loop-through-xml-nodes-in-php)*.

I am using `addChild()` to add another `<comment>` element as a child of the root element. I used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098093/how-to-append-to-a-xml-file-with-php-preferably-with-simplexml) question:

```
$file = "comments.xml";

$comment = $xml -> comment;

$comment -> addChild("user","User2245");
$comment -> addChild("date","02.10.2018");
$comment -> addChild("text","The comment text goes here");

$xml -> asXML($file)
```

Now, when I echo the file contents:

```
foreach($xml -> children() as $comments) { 
  echo $comments -> user . ", "; 
  echo $comments -> date . ", "; 
  echo $comments -> text . "<br>";
}
```

I only get the old file contents (with no changes):

```
User4251,02.10.2018,Comment body goes here
User8650,02.10.2018,Comment body goes here
```

I am using the same **comments.xml** file. There are no errors displayed.

Why doesn't the child element get appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding to one of the `comment` elements, add it to the full doc.

```
$xml = new simplexmlelement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<comments><comment>
  <user>User4251</user>
  <date>02.10.2018</date>
  <text>Comment body goes here</text>
</comment>
<comment>
  <user>User8650</user>
  <date>01.10.2018</date>
  <text>Comment body goes here</text>
</comment></comments>');
$child = $xml->addchild('comment');
$child->addChild("user","User2245");
$child->addChild("date","02.10.2018");
$child->addChild("text","The comment text goes here");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

https://3v4l.org/Pln6U

Answer (score 1):

If you output the full XML, with `echo $xml->asXML()`, you will see that, as you requested, *additional child nodes have been added* to the first comment node:

```
<comment>
    <user>User4251</user>
    <date>02.10.2018</date> 
    <text>Comment body goes here</text> 
    <user>User2245</user><date>02.10.2018</date><text>The comment text goes here</text>
</comment>
```

The reason only the first `comment` has been changed is the same reason that your `echo` doesn't show the new values: if you reference an element like `$xml->comment` or `$comment->user`, you get the *first* child element with that name; it's just short-hand for `$xml->comment[0]` or `$comment->user[0]`. This is actually really handy for navigating through XML documents, because you don't have to know whether there's one or several elements with a particular name, you can write `$xml->comment->user` or `$xml->comment[0]->user[0]` or `$xml->comment->user[0]` and so on.

Since you called `addChild`, the new `user`, `date`, and `text` aren't the first children with that name, so they don't show up in your output.

If what you wanted was to create *a new comment*, you would need to add that first:

```
$comment = $xml->addChild('comment');
$comment->addChild('user', 'User2245');
```

If what you wanted was to *change the values* of the child elements, you can just write to them instead of adding a new child:

```
$comment = $xml->comment[0]; // or just $comment = $xml->comment;
$comment->user = 'User2245';
```

Or you could add something to *each of* the existing comments (note that here we use `$xml->comment` as though it was an array; again, SimpleXML will let us do this whether there's one or several matching elements):

```
foreach ( $xml->comment as $comment ) {
    $comment->addChild('modified', 'true');
}
```